# Not functioning circuits in home, many Breakers reading as bad but not tripped

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, corrosion

Having intervented power issues in areas of the house went to breaker box multiple in Mass breaker failure. No I don't think they failed they are carrying voltage only 24 volts. While others are carrying the full 220-ish to 120 ish. Breakers are extremely cheap went ahead and bought a bunch of Siemens Breakers that swap them out and cleaned the wires of corrosion, tighten down all lugs.

After finishing this everything was seemingly functioning as required, then somebody turned the power off or fliped switch on off to make the lights flicker. I was standing in front of the regular board while that happened after I just installed the new Breakers and tested them reading 120 volts on all Breakers.. I didn't see  anything in box nor  hear anything. But I did notice a room light go out. Upon recheck same problem but with new Breakers and I used some of the older Breakers as well and some of those that weren't working are now working.  At this stage I've spent a great deal more time on it than I was thinking I needed to. And I completely shut everything down just started ripping out handfuls of Breakers.

[image]

Here's what I think is root cause. See pic.. It's been shorted many many many times also lightning..and see goo on 100amp poles..wth is that yellow slime in the contacts and on pole..both sides of panel were on similar condition. I seriously considered purchasing another breaker box with new mains just to make sure everything was sound.. but upon president inspection I really didn't see anything wrong with the steel Inside the Box.  I mean all the welds are fine everything was screwed together it wasn't falling apart.. I'm going to pull out my drill at a grind your disc and a heavy duty wire disk and went to town on the bus in anywhere else I thought looks suspicious sorry I didn't close a finish result picture but I was cleaning down to the original metal all the plastic and rubber was still intact on it.. the people were out of power late at night so I just kind of wanted to hurry up and get it back on for him so far and there's been no problems it seems to be solved I think it would have been solved without replacing the breakers.. and just getting all that corruption corrosion off the panel healed it. But if anybody can give me any knowledge and with that yellow stuff is on that it's on the breaker and bus is it fungus or some kind of excretion? I guess it comes down to everything not making full contact all the time.

Comment: There is no picture.

Comment: A picture of the inside of your panel would be nice along with manufacturer information.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of what you're seeing?

Comment: only one picture was attached ... no placeholder in text, so it did not show

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say you are killing one of the phases probably because the inverter is bad or there is an excessive load on that phase.

Comment: @JamesSofge please edit your post so that only relevant info is included  ... things like the following is just clutter ... `the people were out of power late at night so I just kind of wanted to hurry up and get it back on for him`

Comment: Can you please post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door?

Comment: I want you to know that one of my absolutely worst peeves of all are working fuse boxes nothing labeled in them, on them, or vastly mislabeled. I mean a break or two I understand. It happens. But everything other than one or two that is just completely unacceptable it's a nightmare, or just very very inconvenient..There are no indicators on anything just judging by amperage what should be or trace it down n tag it.

Comment: @JamesSofge -- can you get us that photo anyway though? I need to see the manufacturer labeling on this box...